# jquery click function with different database id

Tags: php, jquery

So I have a..

.php

```
<?php
    while($row = $results->fetch())
    {
        ?>
        <span class="rss-badge" id="<?php echo $row['id_ilmoitus'] ?>">Enlarge</span>
        <br />
        <?php
    }
?>
```

.jquery

```
$("<?php echo $row['id_ilmoitus] ?>").click(function(){
   alert("pressed", "<?php echo $row['id_ilmoitus] ?>");
});
```

My plan is to make that specific span to do something. So that is why I want every span have different Ids and jquery to use. There are numerous id's in database.

Comment: so what is the output of `$("<?php echo $row['id_ilmoitus] ?>")`?

Comment: $row['id_ilmoitus] is a integer

Comment: Why cannot you put them all in same class and call them through one `click` function?

Comment: dont you need you push # before that

Comment: id shouldn't start with a number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all your syntax is wrong you are missing **#** before that.

Secondly,Instead of adding multiple event on every id, add one on **class** selector and get id of the item clicked:

```
$('span.rss-badge').click(function(){
   alert("pressed"+ this.id);
});
```

Answer (score 7):

Try something like this :

```
$('.rss-badge').on('click',function(){
    alert($(this).id);
    //--- LET'S DO IT 
});
```

Comment: please do with event delegation

Answer (score 1):

Basically you are using wrong selector at first, in your html rendering an id cannot start with numbers it should be an alphabetic character.

```
<?php
    while($row = $results->fetch())
    {
        ?>
        <span class="rss-badge" id="data<?php echo $row['id_ilmoitus'] ?>">Enlarge</span>
        <br />
        <?php
    }
?>
```

`$('#id')` is the correct selector if you want to bind click event

```
var id = "#data<?php echo $row['id_ilmoitus]; ?>";

$(id).click(function(){
   alert("pressed", "<?php echo $row['id_ilmoitus] ?>");
});
```

Comment: var id = "#<?php echo $row['id_ilmoitus]; ?>";

Resulting id will be something like #23. Which is an invalid id. ID must start with an alphabet. So append an alphabet after #.

Comment: @LeoTAbraham This has been weakened in HTML5, but it's still a good practice not to have id's start with a number.